# How to clone using Paperclip without reupload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
new_image = UserImage.create(:upload => images.upload)
new_image.save
self.user_images << new_image
```

it will create a new file in s3 with same content.

How do I make them to point to the same url?

If it is not possible , should i start to open a issue and fork it in Paperclip?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
new_image = UserImage.create(:upload => images.upload)
if new_image.save
  self.user_images = new_image.upload if new_image.upload.exists?
end
```